# XML to XML Transformation using XSLT- Loop over child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am just starting out on XSLT and need help with the following :-

Here is my XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT>
<METADATA>
  <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Site_ID" TYPE="TEXT" />
  <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Road_Name" TYPE="TEXT" />
  <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="KM" TYPE="NUMBER" />
</METADATA>
<RESULTSET FOUND="1">
  <ROW MODID="16" RECORDID="38664">
     <COL>
        <DATA>SI-3158</DATA>
     </COL>
     <COL>
        <DATA>Upper Taylor Main</DATA>
     </COL>
     <COL>
        <DATA>12.61</DATA>
     </COL>
  </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

In the XML above the value of first "FIELD" node corresponds to value of first "DATA" node. I wanted to transform the above XML in following way

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<COLUMN>
 <NAME>Site_ID</NAME>
 <TYPE>TEXT</TYPE>
 <NULLABLE>YES</NULLABLE>
 <MAXREPEAT>1</MAXREPEAT>
 <VALUE>SI-3158</VALUE>
</COLUMN>
<COLUMN>
 <NAME>Road_Name</NAME>
 <TYPE>TEXT</TYPE>
 <NULLABLE>YES</NULLABLE>
 <MAXREPEAT>1</MAXREPEAT>
 <VALUE>Upper Taylor Main</VALUE>
</COLUMN>
<COLUMN>
 <NAME>KM</NAME>
 <TYPE>NUMBER</TYPE>
 <NULLABLE>YES</NULLABLE>
 <MAXREPEAT>1</MAXREPEAT>
 <VALUE>12.61</VALUE>
</COLUMN>
```

Here is what I have done so far :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/FMPXMLRESULT/">
<xsl:for-each select="FIELD"> 
<COLUMN>
 <NAME><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></NAME>
 <TYPE><xsl:value-of select="@TYPE"/></TYPE>
 <NULLABLE><xsl:value-of select="@EMPTYOK"/></NULLABLE>
 <MAXREPEAT><xsl:value-of select="@MAXREPEAT"/></MAXREPEAT>
 <VALUE><xsl:value-of select="../../RESULTSET/ROW/COL/DATA"/></VALUE>
</COLUMN>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With my XSLT the value first "Data" node gets added to "VALUE" attribute of each "FIELD", I need to way to loop over the each "COL" node.

Secondly I have seen various posts not recommending the use of "xsl:for-each", so  is there a better to accomplish what I need. Thanks in advance

Comment: What if there's more than ROW?

Comment: @michael.hor257k there is only supposed to be one row. Thanks for the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempted stylesheet, you need to change:

```
<xsl:template match="/FMPXMLRESULT/">
<xsl:for-each select="FIELD">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="/FMPXMLRESULT">
<xsl:for-each select="METADATA/FIELD">
```

to make it work as expected - except for the value part, that needs to be fetched by its position.

Note that the result is not a well-formed XML document, as it has no single root element.

There is nothing wrong with using `xsl:for-each` for this.

Comment: Yup, this is much more elegant.

Comment: @friedemann_bach Except I missed the part about fetching the corresponding value...

Comment: ... well, right. It's still less "invasive" concerning the original code.

Comment: @DeepjyotMaher I don't see your modified stylesheet, so I cannot tell what's wrong with it. See a working example here: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7m4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="METADATA/FIELD">
        <COLUMN>
            <NAME>
                <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
            </NAME>
            <TYPE>
                <xsl:value-of select="@TYPE"/>
            </TYPE>
            <NULLABLE>
                <xsl:value-of select="@EMPTYOK"/>
            </NULLABLE>
            <MAXREPEAT>
                <xsl:value-of select="@MAXREPEAT"/>
            </MAXREPEAT>
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position() div 2"/>
            <VALUE>
                <xsl:value-of select="//FMPXMLRESULT/RESULTSET/ROW/COL[$position]/DATA"/>
            </VALUE>
        </COLUMN>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="RESULTSET"/>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates the desired result. Use xsl:template instead of xsl:for-each, whenever you can.